# Работа нескольких сайтов в docker, как лучше организовать работу

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть несколько сайтов, есть `docker-compose` c запущенными контейнерами
`nginx + php7 + php5 + mysql + adminer`. Снаружи вертится `nginx-proxy`. 
Подскажите, как лучше организовать работу нескольких сайтов. 
Есть варианты:

1. Через работу данных контейнеров с запуском одного
   `docker-compose.yml`  и проброса сайтов в один установленный
   контейнер с `nginx (php + mysql + adminer` так же едины)
2. Под каждый сайт запустить свой контейнер с `nginx (php + mysql +
   adminer` так же едины)
3. Отдельный `docker-compose.yml` для каждого сайта с запуском всех
   четырех контейнеров под каждый сайт?
4. Какой то еще вариант ?

Что скажите, как правильно?

Comment: В Вашем случае, больше подойдёт вариант №3.

Comment: @TonySt., хорошо бы расписать, чем он лучше остальных вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Как я себе представляю архитектуру подходящего решения:

На условном 80/443 порту висит nginx, проксирующий запросы на разные сайты. Далее количество `docker-compose`, равное количеству сайтов, где каждый из элементов(nginx + php7 + php5 + mysql + adminer), скорее всего, находится в отдельном контейнере, если только что-то не связано между собой очень плотно.

Плюсы такого решения - соблюдение принципы единственной ответственности. Ведь у нас, по сути разные системы. У них могут быть разные настройки каждого из элементов, и вносить изменения(переподнимать контейнеры) для них нужно будет с разной периодичностью.

Кроме того, при возросшей нагрузке, ничего не меняя, вы сможете в пару кликов перенести один из сайтов на другую машину.